# Unable to Push source code to Bzr/Bazaar

Tags: version-control, bazaar, tortoisebzr

I am having issues pushing my codes into my Bazaar repository. It worked earlier for my first commit but not it does not work at all. Everytime I try to push my codes, I get this exception

```
Error while executing push
[Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\benjam~1.won\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpj2hcal.pag'
```

Any idea how I resolve this? I have even deleted the repo and .git folder and tried again but I keep getting this error regardless of the branch I guess.

I am using this as my machine :

Windows Vista Business 32 bit

4GB RAM

Eclipse + Aptana

Comment: Sounds like the problem with either bzr-eclipse or xmloutput plugin.

Comment: So do you recommend me removing all of the Bazaar stuff and reinstalling them or just the XML plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, bialix was right. There was indeed an issue with the xmloutput plugin. Reinstalling it seems to have done the trick.

Thanks bialix !!